# AVFoundation code produces no ID3 metadata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

This is my code which is not working for any mp3 files:

```
           //define AVassets
                NSURL *assetUrl2 = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                [assetLoc stringByAppendingPathComponent:title]] 
                URLByAppendingPathExtension:ext]

                AVAsset *asset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetUrl2 
                options:nil];

           //print asset url       
                NSString *encodedString = [assetUrl2 absoluteString];  
                NSLog(@"song name%@",encodedString); //this prints the valid url

                NSArray *origMetadata = 
                [asset2 metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatID3Metadata];
               for (AVMetadataItem *item in origMetadata) {
               NSLog(@"*** ID3 tags found");
               NSString *keys = (NSString *)[item key];
               NSString *value = [item stringValue];
               NSLog(@"value for tag:%@ is:%@", keys, value);
            }
```

**However, if I swap...**

```
`NSArray *origMetadata = 
[asset2 metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatID3Metadata];`
```

**with...**

```
`NSArray *origMetadata = 
[asset2 metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatiTunesMetadata];`
```

and load an AAC file rather than an MP3 file, it works. Obviously I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the files on device contain ID3 metadata?

Comment: Yes the file does have ID3, as I can see it in itunes. Further, I can bring out the ID3 data using `songArtist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];`. However, I need to use avfoundation because I will need to edit the ID3.